# OpenNI missing frames from Kinect when reading from ".oni" file

Tags: kinect, frames, openni

I have a simple question for OpenNI:

If I use the basic example to read from a Kinect (or a ".oni" file) like this :

```
// Missing init
while(true) {
    // Read a new frame
    rc = g_context.WaitAnyUpdateAll();

    g_depth.GetMetaData(g_depthMD);

    mystuff();
}
// Missing close
```

If the mystuff() operations take let's say 100ms, will the next frames be skipped (because Kinect is 30FPS so 33 ms per frame) and I'll miss them or is there any buffer to save them in the Kinect or OpenNI ? Let's say I save some JPEG to the disk and I don't get all images (timestamp : 0,33,66,133,200,...)

Another problem :

Whenever I save to a ".oni" file and then read from it, frames are missing, is this because writing to the disk makes the program skip frames (same scenario as above, but within the [Record()](http://kinectcar.ronsper.com/docs/openni/tut_recording.html) method)? When I read from live Kinect all frames are there (timestamp : 0,33,66,100,133,166,200,...)

Comment: I can answer your second problem. The Kinect may get 30 fps, but if you do something with it (including saving into disk) then you will consume time. If in this time you get another frame, and your program is busy then this frame will be omitted and you'll get the next one...So at the end you'll have like 20 fps. My suggestion is not to use ONI, save the info as images or PCD files and load them in the speed you need it... Also I sugggest to save first in memory and then dump it in the hard drive if you have enough RAM

Comment: thank you, that was exactly what I needed to know and haven't found somewhere else. If you have some source that talks about this more in details, feel free to share it.
In my case, I have to save it as .oni because I need to link my measures to my results so that anyone can redo them and I have no time to implement a custom way to save the information.

Comment: I would't recommend ONI. Also you may take a look to openni2 they have something that you can choose the frame you want to use, though ONI from openni 1 and 2 are not compatible... I created a capturing tool for my work that saves the data in differente formats that you may use if you want https://github.com/cvlabbonn/tools_openni2

Answer (score 0):

OpenNI seems to be designed by default to playback the frames at the rate that they are recorded, based on the timestamp stored with each frame. This means by default if some processing is done between two frame reads, some frames could have been skipped.

If OpenNI2 is used, set the playback speed to -1. This will cause all frames to be read manually, i.e., each frame is to be read through VideoStream::readFrame() one by one, and there will have no frames skipped or missed.

```cpp
device.getPlaybackControl()->setSpeed(-1);
```

Note that OpenNI 1 (1.5.7 as far as I know) does not allow playback speed to set to -1 so might need a different way to read frames out one by one.

Comment: thanks, but I was stuck with OpenNI 1 at the time, but it's good to know if some other people need the information